# React PDF download with react-pdf not sure what I am doing wrong

Tags: reactjs, pdf

I am trying to download a page in PDF format using the [React-PDF](https://react-pdf.org/) package. For instance I am trying to download the  User's Profile Information. I am using `<PDFDownloadLink>` on the `index.js` file and at the User's Page Component I am wrapping it with the `<Document>` component from the react-pdf. However the page suddenly is giving me the error `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'match')`

That's in the the index.js

````js
<PDFDownloadLink
        document={<ParticipantProfile participant={participant} />}
        fileName="somename.pdf"
      >
        {({ loading }) => (loading ? 'Loading document...' : 'Download now!')}
      </PDFDownloadLink>```
    
Here is in the User's page



return (
    <Document>
      <View>
.....
</View>
</Document>
````

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
<PDFViewer style={styles.PDFContainer}>
    <InvoicePage user={user} invoice={viewInvoice} />
</PDFViewer>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    PDFContainer: {
        width: "100%",
        height: "50vh", //As per your page layout 
    }
}
```